# Getting [object SVGSVGElement] instead of SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a "group" of SVGs at the bottom of my HTML page, hidden. I am trying to conditionally use them based on object keys. For instance, I have:

```
<svg id="fiftyOne" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 2863 871" ...../></svg>
```

And I want to conditionally call `#fiftyOne` as the svg logo inside of this Javascript Template:

```
const refreshView = (dataSet) => {
    output.innerHTML = "";
    dataSet.forEach((p) => {
      output.innerHTML += `
        
        <div class="card pickup-result" data-output="${p.output}" data-tone="${p.tone}">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-heading">
            <h4>${p.name}</h4>${p.svg}   <// Call the SVG here.
          </div>
          <hr>
         
          <h5>Specs:</h5>
          <p><strong>Output: </strong> ${p.output}</p>
          <p><strong>Description:</strong> ${p.description}</p>
  
          <div class="pickup-info">
          <a class="link-button" target="blank" href="${p.url}">See Product</a>
           
          </div>
        </div>
        
        </div>
        `;
    });
```

But I'm getting the rendered card, with `[object SVGSVGElement]` instead of the rendered SVG. Am I doing something wrong?

---

UPDATE:

Using `p.svg.outerHTML` works to fill the HTML with the proper information. The next problem I'm facing is the SVG won't show up on the actual card, even though the data is there. See screenshots: [image: Screenshot of Dev Tools]

Any Ideas? This is the first time working with SVGs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are putting a live SVG element into the code instead of its source.

You can output `p.svg.outerHTML` instead of just `p.svg`.

---

Or if you wanted to include that actual element and not a copy of it, you'd have to insert the element after you rendered the HTML entirely (not after each iteration because element references get invalidated every time you set innerHTML as all the contents are reconstructed):

```js
const headers = Array.from(output.querySelectorAll('.card-heading'))
dataSet.forEach((p, index) => headers[index].appendChild(p.svg))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm getting the HTML now, but for some reason, it's "greyed out" in my Firefox Dev Tools. There is no style applied to it. Does that have something to do with the method I'm taking vs your recommended method?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to with that, no style being applied...

Comment: Sorry - On Firefox, greyed out HTML usually means there is `display: none;` applied to the element. The SVG and the paths are just simply greyed out and it does not display on the card itself. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the computed styles and see if there is any CSS elsewhere causing it to be hidden...

Comment: I believe it's the Firefox Source Code: `@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/2000/svg);
@namespace xml url(http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace);

style, script {
 display: none;
}

/*
 * This is only to be overridden by the rule right below.
 *
 * NOTE(emilio): NodeCouldBeRendered in SVGUseElement.cpp relies on this.
 */
symbol {
 display: none !important;
}
`

Comment: That is OK though, since [`<symbol>` is a template for later use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol), it doesn't have any visual representation on its own. Maybe you approached the whole thing the wrong way - possibly you should output all those template SVGs that you'll need in one place permanently, and when you construct your card you just do `<svg><use xlink:href="#theRelevantSymbolIdHere"/></svg>`? But, if you have more issues there, please open a new question, because this one was about how to get the SVG inserted in the first place, which was resolved.

Comment: I actually got it working by changing the template to `<svg><use xlink:href="#${p.svg}" /></svg>` and calling the ID as a string. Thanks a ton for your help!